# Update test execution status in QC using Rest API + Python

Tags: python, rest, automated-tests, robotframework, hp-quality-center

I want to update the test results of Robot framework to QC using Rest api.
By fetching the output.xml file of robot framework, I want to update the test results to QC using rest api.

To do that, I've started develop the scripts using HP ALM 11 Rest api's with  python requests and ElementTree modules.

Right now I can able to authenticate, store cookies and retrieve the defects, test ids, test instances from QC.

But now I want to update the test execution status in the test lab of QC, I've tried as below:
   - Using post method of test instance by query the test-set id and testcase-id.

```
requests.put(self.url + u'/qcbin/rest/domains/<Domain name>/projects/<Project name>/test-instances/query={id[1];test-id[3]}', headers=self.header, data=xml, auth=(self.username,self.__password))
```

But I got below error

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><QCRestException><Id>qccore.general-error</Id><Title>Not Found</Title><StackTrace>javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException&#xD;
at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.FindResourceMethodHandler.handleRequest(FindResourceMethodHandler.java:84)&#xD;
at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)&#xD;
at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)&#xD;
at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:61)&#xD;
at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.FindRootResourceHandler.handleRequest(FindRootResourceHandler.java:93)&#xD;
at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)&#xD;
at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)&#xD;
at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:61)&#xD;
at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.HeadMethodHandler.handleRequest(HeadMethodHandler.java:53)&#xD;
at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)&#xD;
at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)&#xD;
at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:61)&#xD;
at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.OptionsMethodHandler.handleRequest(OptionsMethodHandler.java:46)&#xD;
at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)&#xD;
at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)&#xD;
at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:61)&#xD;
at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.SearchResultHandler.handleRequest(SearchResultHandler.java:33)&#xD;
at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)&#xD;
at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)&#xD;
at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:61)&#xD;
at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.run(AbstractHandlersChain.java:48)&#xD;
at org.apache.wink.server.internal.RequestProcessor.handleRequestWithoutFaultBarrier(RequestProcessor.java:163)&#xD;
at org.apache.wink.server.internal.RequestProcessor.handleRequest(RequestProcessor.java:137)&#xD;
at org.apache.wink.server.internal.servlet.RestServlet.service(RestServlet.java:116)&#xD;
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)&#xD;
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)&#xD;
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)&#xD;
at org.hp.qc.web.restapi.RESTApiFilter.doFilter(RESTApiFilter.java:67)&#xD;
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)&#xD;
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)&#xD;
at org.hp.qc.web.restapi.performance.PerformanceMonitorRESTFilter.doFilter(PerformanceMonitorRESTFilter.java:45)&#xD;
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)&#xD;
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)&#xD;
at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:378)&#xD;
at com.hp.sw.bto.ast.security.lwsso.authenticator.springSecurity.SpringSecurity2LWSSOIntegrationFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurity2LWSSOIntegrationFilter.java:182)&#xD;
at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)&#xD;
at org.hp.qc.web.restapi.sessionmanagement.ImplicitSessionFilter.doFilter(ImplicitSessionFilter.java:54)&#xD;
at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)&#xD;
at org.springframework.security.intercept.web.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:109)&#xD;
at org.springframework.security.intercept.web.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)&#xD;
at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)&#xD;
at com.hp.sw.bto.ast.security.lwsso.authenticator.springSecurity.LWSSO2SpringSecurityIntegrationFilter.doFilter(LWSSO2SpringSecurityIntegrationFilter.java:299)&#xD;
at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)&#xD;
at org.springframework.security.ui.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilterHttp(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:101)&#xD;
at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)&#xD;
at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)&#xD;
at org.springframework.security.context.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.doFilterHttp(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.java:235)&#xD;
at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)&#xD;
at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)&#xD;
at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:175)&#xD;
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:237)&#xD;
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167)&#xD;
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)&#xD;
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)&#xD;
at com.mercury.optane.core.state.ServerStatusFilter.doFilter(ServerStatusFilter.java:33)&#xD;
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)&#xD;
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)&#xD;
at org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)&#xD;
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)&#xD;
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)&#xD;
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:235)&#xD;
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)&#xD;
at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:190)&#xD;
at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:92)&#xD;
at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.process(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:126)&#xD;
at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.invoke(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:70)&#xD;
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)&#xD;
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)&#xD;
at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:158)&#xD;
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)&#xD;
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:330)&#xD;
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:829)&#xD;
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:598)&#xD;
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)&#xD;
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)&#xD;
```

Can some please help me on this error to be solved? or suggest any approach to update the test execution status to QC?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
requests.put(self.url + u'/qcbin/rest/domains/<Domain name>/projects/<Project name>/test-instances/query={id[1];test-id[3]}', headers=self.header, data=xml, auth=(self.username,self.__password))
```

Query structure which you have mentioned is fundamentally wrong.

instead of

```
/test-instances/query={id[1];test-id[3]}
```

use

```
/test-instances?query={id[1];test-id[3]}
```

In general, any url containing query parameter starts with **'?'** and if there are more than one it should be appended by **'&'**

Answer (score 0):

see here: https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/9298/alm-qc-api-update-test-execution-in-a-test-set

figured it out

I had to pull the "id" value from the GET query and use that on the following PUT call:
PUT http://host:port/qcbin/rest/domains/domain/projects/project/test-instances/[id_from_GET_call]

Hope this helps. I searched about 1h for just this answer...